# Double baking / endorsing

Tags: node, baker, accuser, double-baking

For research work, I need to do double baking on mainnet, what is the possibility to do this, I ran two copies of the baker on two servers, but it didn't work due to the fitness too low error

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to disconnect the second node from the network just before the second baker injects its block. In this way the block of the first node does not reach the second node. The two nodes will have (possibly) different blocks at the same level and round (to make sure they are different, you may also try to inject a transaction in the second node). After the baker injects, then you reconnect the second node.

I'm not completely sure this is sufficient.

Comment: what do you think if I run two bakers with different --minimal-fees and make a transaction before the block that I have to bake so that one baker accepts the transaction from the commission, and the second one does not accept it, I will get different hashes and will there be a successful inject?

Comment: I guess this ensures that the block are different. But this alone does not solve your initial problem, that the baker cannot inject because it has already seen a block with the same fitness; see also here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/shell/validation.html#fitness. That's why I suggested also temporarily disconnecting the nodes.